# Is there any way to run a program with a void function prototype within another void function prototype?

Tags: c++

This question originates from a problem I am attempting to solve for an "Introduction to Structured Programming" C++ class.

The problem statement is as follows:

> The program asks the user if he or she wants to convert from feet and inches to meters and centimeters or from meters and centimeters to feet and inches. the program then performs the desired conversion. have the user respond by typing the integer 1 for one type of conversion and 2 for the other conversion. The program reads the user's answer and then executes and if-else statement. Each brand of the if-else statement will be a function call. the 2 functions called in the if-else statement will have function definitions that are very similar to the programs for the previous 2 Practice Programs. Thus, they will be function definitions that call other functions in their function bodies. include a loop that lets the user repeat this computation for new input values until the user says he or she wants to end the program.

For the "previous 2 Practice Programs," I already solved them wholly by using `void` function prototypes. The first program was to convert feet and inches into meters and centimeters. The second program was to convert meters back into feet and inches.

When I run my attempt to the question above in Visual Studio, the compiler suggests an `expected ";"` after the first `void input(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)` and the other `void input` within `void ConvertToEnglish()`. Even when I input the semicolons, the variables within those `void` scopes are now unknown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void input(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters);//Needed function prototype for inputs
//Declared reference values:
//Feet as reference int and inches, meters, centimeters as reference doubles
//Declarations carried out through each prototype

void conversion(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters);//Needed function prototype for conversion calc

void output(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters);//Needed function prototype for outputs

void ConvertToMetric();
void ConvertToEnglish();

int main()
{
    char ans;  //loop control variable
    int which; //stores the choice of conversion
    do
    {
        //Add a loop here to ensure that the user enters either 1 or 2

        cout << "\nEnter 1 for English to Metric or " << endl
            << "Enter 2 for Metric to English conversion"
            << endl;
        cin >> which;
        if (1 == which)
            ConvertToMetric();//calls the ConvertToMetric functions
        else
            ConvertToEnglish();//calss the ConvertToEnglish functions

        cout << "Y or y allows another choice of conversion. "
            << "any other quits" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    } while ('y' == ans || 'Y' == ans);
    return 0;
}

void ConvertToMetric()
{
    void input(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for user inputs
    {
        cout << "Enter feet as an integer: ";
        cin >> feet;//User inputs feet as integer
        cout << "Enter inches as double: ";
        cin >> inches;//User inputs inches as double

        if (feet < 0 || inches < 0)//If statement when either feet or inches is equal to zero or negative
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n"
                << endl;//Required output for invalid input
            cout << "Enter feet as an integer: ";//User goes through process again
            cin >> feet;
            cout << "Enter inches as double: ";
            cin >> inches;
        }
    }

    void conversion(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for imperial to metric conversions
    {
        meters = feet * 0.3048;//Converts inputted feet to meters
        centimeters = (inches / 12) * 0.3048;//Converts inputted inches to feet then to meters
        meters += centimeters;//Adds both calculated values together to get total meters
    }

    void output(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for value outputs
    {
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);//Decimal precision to two the hundreths place
        cout << meters << " meters corresponds to " << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches\n";//Required output for all values
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void ConvertToEnglish()
{
    void input(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for user inputs
    {
        cout << "Enter a number of meters as a double\n";
        cin >> meters;//User inputs meters as double

        if (meters < 0)//If statement when either meters is equal to zero or negative
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n"
                << endl;//Required output for invalid input
            cout << "Enter a number of meters as a double\n";//User goes through process again
            cin >> meters;
        }
    }

    void conversion(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for imperial to metric conversions
    {
        double feetDec = meters / 0.3048;//To get double num
        feet = meters / 0.3048;//True value of inputted meters converted into feet
        int feetInt = floor(meters / 0.3048);//To get integer num
        inches = (feetDec - feetInt) * 12;//Calc for decimal part of num converted into inches
    }

    void output(int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)//Function prototype for value outputs
    {
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);//Decimal precision to two the hundreths place
        cout << meters << " meters corresponds to " << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches\n";//Required output for all values
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the text "call other functions in their function bodies" means that the called function bodies, such as the body of the `input(...)` function, exist inside the calling function e.g. `ConvertToMetric()`. It means the calls to those functions are made from within the calling function. Move the embedded functions out and ensure they have unique names. Then call the relevant functions from within `ConvertToMetric()` and `ConvertToEnglish()`.

Comment: C++ does not directly support local function. However lambda functions could be used for that : `auto input = [](int& feet, double& inches, double& meters, double& centimeters) -> void { /* code here ... */ };`

Answer (score 2):

This code inside of `ConvertToMetric()` and `ConvertToEnglish()` is all wrong.  You can't implement nested functions inside of functions like you are trying to do (well, you can, using [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), but that is a whole other subject, and is not what this assignment is asking for).

You have forward-declared the inner functions above `main()`, which is fine (but unnecessary, since `main()` does not call them). You just need to move their implementations out to file scope, and then **call** them from inside of `ConvertToMetric()` and `ConvertToEnglish()`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void ConvertToMetric();
void ConvertToEnglish();

int main()
{
    char ans;
    int which;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter 1 for English to Metric or " << endl
            << "Enter 2 for Metric to English"
            << endl;

        cin >> which;
        if (1 == which)
            ConvertToMetric();
        else if (2 == which)
            ConvertToEnglish();
        else {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data\n" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Y or y allows another choice of conversion. Any other quits" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    } while ('y' == ans || 'Y' == ans);
    return 0;
}

void inputEnglish(int& feet, double& inches)
{
    do {
        cout << "Enter feet as an integer: ";
        if (cin >> feet) {
            if (feet >= 0) 
                break;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;
    } while (true);

    do {
        cout << "Enter inches as double: ";
        if (cin >> inches) {
            if (inches >= 0) 
                break;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;
    } while (true);
}

void conversionEnglishToMetric(int feet, double inches, double& meters, double& centimeters)
{
    meters = feet * 0.3048;
    centimeters = (inches / 12) * 0.3048;
    meters += centimeters;
}

void outputMetric(int feet, double inches, double meters, double centimeters)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches corresponds to " << meters << " meters, " << centimeters << " centimeters\n";
    cout << endl;
}

void ConvertToMetric()
{
    int feet;
    double inches, meters, centimeters;
    
    inputEnglish(feet, inches);
    conversionEnglishToMetric(feet, inches, meters, centimeters);
    outputMetric(feet, inches, meters, centimeters);
}

void inputMetric(double& meters, double& centimeters)
{
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number of meters as a double\n";
        if (cin >> meters) {
            if (meters >= 0)
                break;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;     
    } while (true);
    
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number of centimeters as a double\n";
        if (cin >> centimeters) {
            if (centimeters >= 0)
                break;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;     
    } while (true);
}

void conversionMetricToEnglish(double meters, double centimeters, int& feet, double& inches)
{
    // TODO: fix this to take centimeters into account correctly!
    double feetDec = meters / 0.3048;
    feet = meters / 0.3048;
    int feetInt = floor(meters / 0.3048);
    inches = (feetDec - feetInt) * 12;
}

void outputEnglish(double meters, double centimeters, int feet, double inches)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << meters << " meters, " << centimeters << " centimeters corresponds to " << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches\n";
    cout << endl;
}

void ConvertToEnglish()
{
    int feet;
    double inches, meters, centimeters;
    
    inputMetric(meters, centimeters);
    conversionMetricToEnglish(meters, centimeters, feet, inches);
    outputEnglish(meters, centimeters, feet, inches);
}
```

Alternatively, using lambdas instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void ConvertToMetric();
void ConvertToEnglish();

int main()
{
    char ans;  //loop control variable
    int which; //stores the choice of conversion
    do
    {
        //Add a loop here to ensure that the user enters either 1 or 2

        cout << "\nEnter 1 for English to Metric or " << endl
            << "Enter 2 for Metric to English conversion"
            << endl;
        cin >> which;
        if (1 == which)
            ConvertToMetric();//calls the ConvertToMetric functions
        else if (2 == which)
            ConvertToEnglish();//calss the ConvertToEnglish functions
        else {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data\n" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Y or y allows another choice of conversion. "
            << "any other quits" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    } while ('y' == ans || 'Y' == ans);
    return 0;
}

void ConvertToMetric()
{
    int feet;
    double inches, meters, centimeters;
    
    auto input = [&]() {
        do {
            cout << "Enter feet as an integer: ";
            if (cin >> feet) {
                if (feet >= 0) 
                    break;
            }
            else {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;
        } while (true);

        do {
            cout << "Enter inches as double: ";
            if (cin >> inches) {
                if (inches >= 0) 
                    break;
            }
            else {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;
        } while (true);
    };

    auto conversion = [&]() {
        meters = feet * 0.3048;
        centimeters = (inches / 12) * 0.3048;
        meters += centimeters;
    };

    auto output = [&]() {
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        cout << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches corresponds to " << meters << " meters, " << centimeters << " centimeters\n";
        cout << endl;
    };

    input();
    conversion();
    output();
}

void ConvertToEnglish()
{
    auto input = [&]() {
        do {
            cout << "Enter a number of meters as a double\n";
            if (cin >> meters) {
                if (meters >= 0)
                    break;
            }
            else {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;     
        } while (true);
    
        do {
            cout << "Enter a number of centimeters as a double\n";
            if (cin >> centimeters) {
                if (centimeters >= 0)
                    break;
            }
            else {
                cin.clear();
            cin .ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid data - please re-enter\n" << endl;     
        } while (true);
    };

    auto conversion = [&]() {
        // TODO: fix this to take centimeters into account correctly!
        double feetDec = meters / 0.3048;
        feet = meters / 0.3048;
        int feetInt = floor(meters / 0.3048);
        inches = (feetDec - feetInt) * 12;
    };

    auto output = [&]() {
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        cout << meters << " meters, " << centimeters << " centimeters corresponds to " << feet << " feet, " << inches << " inches\n";
        cout << endl;
    };

    input();
    conversion();
    output();
}
```